# SQL и ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ

Tags: sql

возник вопрос.
Есть SQL запрос с WHERE условиями, возможно ли сделать чтобы если не пришло значение в условие, то оно пропускало его?

```
SELECT goods.id as `tovar_id`, 
       goods.name as `tovar_name`, 
       accounting.sale_price as `cennick`, 
       views_sport.name as `sport_name`, 
       category.name as `category_name`,
       manufacturer.id as `manufacturer_id`, 
       manufacturer.name as `manufacturer_name`, 
       goods.description as `tovar_info`, 
       goods.floor as `pol`, 
       accounting.id as `accounting_id`, 
       accounting.number as `colihestvo_zakuplennogo`, 
       accounting.color_id as `color_tovar_id`
FROM manufacturer 
JOIN goods 
  ON goods.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id JOIN category
  ON category.id = goods.category_id 
JOIN views_sport 
  ON views_sport.id = goods.sport 
JOIN accounting 
  ON accounting.goods_id = goods.id 
WHERE (category.id = 3) 
  AND (accounting.color_id = *) 
  AND (goods.manufacturer_id = *) 
ORDER BY accounting_id DESC;
```

Тут где "*" значения могут не прийти, как сделать чтобы если их нет он тупо их пропускал и выполнял по оставшимся условиям, чтобы не писать программу с большим количеством условий. ???

Comment: `колонка IS NOT NULL` и/или делаете INNER JOIN, тогда в выборке будет только пересечение таблиц

Comment: Не могут в принципе. Хоть Null - а подставь.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  goods.id as `tovar_id`, 
  goods.name as `tovar_name`, 
  accounting.sale_price as `cennick`, 
  views_sport.name as `sport_name`, 
  category.name as `category_name`,
  manufacturer.id as `manufacturer_id`, 
  manufacturer.name as `manufacturer_name`, 
  goods.description as `tovar_info`, 
  goods.floor as `pol`, 
  accounting.id as `accounting_id`, 
  accounting.number as 
  `colihestvo_zakuplennogo`, 
  accounting.color_id as `color_tovar_id`
FROM 
  manufacturer 
  JOIN goods ON goods.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id 
  JOIN category ON category.id = goods.category_id 
  JOIN views_sport ON views_sport.id = goods.sport 
  JOIN accounting ON accounting.goods_id = goods.id 
WHERE (category.id = 3) 
  AND ((accounting.color_id = 'XXX') OR ('XXX' = '')) 
  AND ((goods.manufacturer_id = 'XXX') OR ('XXX' = ''))
ORDER BY 
  accounting_id DESC;
```

При таком запросе если вместо XXX придет пустое значение оно пройдет по второму условию(or XXX=''), XXX - переменная которая формируется вашим языком при таком варианте должна передаваться в запрос как строка.

p.s. Пожалуйста форматируйте код, не нужно выдавать его одной строкой